# Landing pages on ExM 3.4 is only showing RedirectUrlPage.aspx

Tags: exm

Whenever we look at email reports in the ExM it only displays links like RedirectUrlPage.aspx, we would like to see the actual destination links people click on. Any idea how to fix this?

[image: Landing Page urls are not helpful]
We are using Sitecore version 8.2 Initial Release with ExM 3.4 Initial Release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `8.2 Initial Release + 3.4 Initial Release`, please request **SC Hotfix 152518-1-CMS 8.2 Initial Release (rev. 160729) EXM 3.4 Initial Release (rev. 161028)** from Sitecore Support.

For others using `8.2 Update 2 + EXM 3.4 Update 1`, please request hotfix **SC Hotfix 151869-1-CMS 8.2 Update 2 (rev. 161221) EXM 3.4 Update 1 (rev. 170105)** from Sitecore Support.

In both cases, there is a package to install on CM servers, and a zip to extract on CD servers.